# Aframe - Select random entity (from 3 options) and set Attribute

Tags: javascript, aframe

Edit: Well thanks to the help of Piotr [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/selective-probation?path=index.html:22:38) is a working example. It takes two random Titles from a JSON array and displays only one at a time (through a process of random selection). Then if the user clicks the Title that belongs to the correct image on the box the font turns green, otherwise if he clicks the Title for a game that doesn't match up with the image then the text turns red. Amazing stuff. Here's some of the code.

```
  AFRAME.registerComponent('json-text-loader', {
  schema: {},
  init: function () {
    var url = 'json/text.json';
    var parentEL = this.el;

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open( 'GET', url, true );
    request.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {

      var game = JSON.parse( event.target.response )
      var keys = Object.keys(game);
      var random = game[keys.length * Math.random() << 0];
      var trivia = random.Title
      var game2 = JSON.parse( event.target.response )
      var keys2 = Object.keys(game);
      var random2 = game[keys.length * Math.random() << 0];
      var trivia2 = random2.Title
      var textEntity = document.querySelector('#text');
      var gurl = random.Imageurl
      var sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene');
      sceneEl.querySelector('a-box').setAttribute('material', {src:gurl}); 
      textEntity.setAttribute("visible", "false")       

    let visibleRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); // THIS ELEMENT WILL BE VISIBLE
    let anwserRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); // THIS IS THE ELEMENT WITH THE CORRECT OPTION

  let children = Array.from(parentEL.children); 
  children.forEach((el, index) => {

if (index == visibleRandom) {
  el.setAttribute("visible", "true")
  el.setAttribute("value", trivia2)

} else {
  el.setAttribute("visible", "false")
}
if (index == anwserRandom) {
  el.setAttribute("value", trivia)
} 
 el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if(el.getAttribute("value") == trivia) {
    el.setAttribute("color", "green")
  } else {
    el.setAttribute("color", "red")
  }
});
});
});
    request.send( null );
  }
});
```

ORIGINAL: Hoping someone can assist with this (if its possible that is). I need a bit of code in my scene to randomly pick one of three  `var textEntity = document.querySelector('#text');` entities to make visible in my scene, and if that randomly chosen element happens to be the first (textEntity1) and gets clicked on by the user the font color becomes green. The value of textEntity1 is always going to be the same so I don't know if that makes it easier to reference?

`textEntity1.setAttribute("value", option1)`

The 'Else' part (if this is going to require an 'if statement') is for when the entity made visible is textEntity2 / 3 and gets clicked on, in which case the font color should change to red.

Current (limited) code:

```
     // select random entity from below and set its attribute as visible                                                   
      var textEntity1 = document.querySelector('#text');
      var textEntity2 = document.querySelector('#text2');
      var textEntity3 = document.querySelector('#text3');

     // trigger event (e.g color change) if visible entity is 'textEntity1' and gets clicked.          
      sceneEl.querySelector('#text').addEventListener('click', function () {
      el.setAttribute('color', '#ffff00');
      });
      } );
```

Looking forward to see if there is a solution to this. So far I've learnt how to do [random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) code for setting positions of objects but this seems a bit more complicated than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few mechanics here. Let me explain how to do the "quiz" part, and i think it will explain the visibility as well.

It may not be the best solution, but it seams neat.
Lets have our three options inside an empty entity. The parent will handle the logic.

```
<a-entity logic>
  <a-box position="0 0 1></a-box>
  <a-box position="0 0 0></a-box>
  <a-box position="0 0 -1></a-box>
</a-entity>
```

Cool. Now lets take a look inside the `logic` component.
I need a random integer between 0-2, the `Math.random()` returns 0-1 (excluding 1), so i need to make `Math.floor(Math.random()*3))`. 
Also I need to grab the references. Since they are `children` of the entity, I don't need a `document.querySelector()`. I'll grab all the entity's children and convert them into an array:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("logic", {
  init: function() {
     let anwser = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
     let children = Array.from(this.el.children);
  }
});
```

Now, lets give them event listeners, in which we check which box is clicked:

```
children.forEach((el, index) => {
    el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      if (index == anwser) {
        el.setAttribute("color", "green")
      } else {
        el.setAttribute("color", "red")
      }
});
```

So, I have the boxes, I have a random anwser, and if that anwser is clicked, the box will turn green.

Moreover You can turn another random anwser invisible, if You put there a `el.setAttribute('visibility', 'false')`

---

Check it out in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pbk93fme/1/). The anwser is printed in the console.

**UPDATE**

If You already have an anwser from a JSON.parse, You an just check if it fits with the visible entity:

```
children.forEach((el, index) => {
    if (index == anwser) {
      el.setAttribute("visible", "true")
    } else {
      el.setAttribute("visible", "false")
    }
    el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      if(el.getAttribute("value") == option1) {
        el.setAttribute("color", "green")
      } else {
        el.setAttribute("color", "red")
      }
    });
}
```

Check out the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pbk93fme/5/).

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm busy trying to wrap my head around it. I really appreciate how you break it down step by step in a way that a new person can learn, so thank you again. I'll let you know when I've got it working.

Comment: @Piotre my answer (option1) is coming from a JSON parse will that make a difference to being able to apply your solution?  example https://jsfiddle.net/3f29esoq/

Comment: @DarioSilva Instead of checking numbers You can check the the text in the `<a-text>` https://jsfiddle.net/55574z02/ ?

Comment: I'm not managing to apply this code. You know that I'm not looking for the code to generate a random answer right? (I already have a set answer that I want to keep from the earlier JSON.parse).

Comment: @DarioSilva I've updated my anwser. The provided code makes a random option visible, and makes it red / green depending on the JSON.parse (which is called option1)

Comment: Do I still need to add the earlier sections e.g let anwser = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); and let children = Array.from(this.el.children);? I dont understand how the JSON.parse got converted to an array and why they need children as a reference. Sorry if I'm sounding stupid but its a bit confusing for me. I'm trying to combine it with this earlier code you helped me with - https://glitch.com/edit/#!/selective-probation?path=index.html:49:8

Comment: @DarioSilva I;ve merged two of Your components, check it out https://glitch.com/edit/#!/salt-existence?path=index.html:51:0

Comment: You're such a star. I've modified the code slightly to get it more in line with custom values.  You've given me a lot to chew on here and I'd love to learn one day how exactly this formula works :)